# can I use Time machine backup to reinstall software applications I have mistakenly erased?

Tags: macos, backup, osx-snow-leopard

I am selling my iMac 2006 and have erased the hard drive - re installing OS Snow Leopard from a retail disc I bought when I upgraded. Now I realise I have probably erased all the software that came with it originally e.g. ilife. I have a Time Machine backup - but I'm not sure whether or how I can use it to reinstall the applications. Would love some help if anyone can tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes you can restore applications from TB backups as I have done this on my very own Macs when upgrading to Yosemite.

Applications like iLife are bound to your Apple ID so you should be able to download then from the store, I believe.

Comment: Thanks!I was able to transfer just applications from my ext hard drive. But had to locate an earlier version of iTunes from TM so it would work.
I created a new user admin account, deleted my old user account. Thought that was finally it but when I logged out it still had my name on the top of the login window! Answer to that was going into Preferences, Sharing - there I could change the name to 'New User's iMac'.

I am leaving the New User account on it - and I will tell whoever buys it what the password is.

Think it's ready to go now! 

Hope that helps someone else avoid all the puzzling :)